# SharePoint 2019 disable invitation email

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I am trying to disable the "Send email invitation" that is ticked by default while you try to grant access to something on SharePoint.

I have found some guides to edit AclInv.aspx f.e. http://sharepointsharks.blog/disable-send-an-email-invitation-when-providing-user-permission/, but it does not seem to work. I have done that on all farm servers and restarted the IIS, but still no luck :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SharePoint 2019,
please go to C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\GLOBAL\seattle.master
Below are the specific codes:
[image]

please see the page
Reference:
http://answers.flyppdevportal.com/MVC/Post/Thread/4a7e6af2-5123-4b9b-b5f3-ac344d1fe852?category=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/108979)

Comment: Gaurravs, thank you .

Comment: Thanks for reply, gonna test it right away! :-)

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2019, To change the default dialog open the AclInv.aspx file located here C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\AclInv.aspx.

Now search for chkSendEmailv15 and change Checked=True to Checked=False.

Reference:

https://theezitguy.wordpress.com/2017/03/26/sharepoint-change-default-setting-of-send-an-email-invitation/

Comment: well. that's exactly what I did... but no luck :-(